# How to set a like button in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-5

Hello I have an exercise app where a user should be able to Like some products.
I could find a way to display the product he liked, but I really can't figure how to create and make work the **like button**.
I am not using any gem, I wan't to understand how to do it from Scratch.

Here are my models:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :likes
  has_many :liked_products, through: :likes, source: :product
end

class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :likes
end

class Like < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :product
end
```

In my view product show where I want the like button:

```
<h1><%= @product.name %></h1>

<%= link_to "Like", product_likes_path(@product), method: :put, remote: true %>
```

my routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root to: 'visitors#index'
  devise_for :users
  resources :users

  resources :products do
    resource :likes
  end
end
```

That's my products controller, I think things must come in here but I don't know HOW!

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :find_product, only: :show

  def index
    @products = Product.all
  end

  def show
    #@product.like  => gives an error 404
  end

  private

  def find_product
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

I had created a likes controller but it seems it is not useful.... So... I gave up there...

```
class LikesController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @like = Like.new(like_params)
  end

  def create
    @like = Like.new(like_params)
  end

  private

  def like_params
    params.require(:likes).permit(:user_id, :product_id)
  end

end
```

I would really enjoy some light on this please :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found out  how to set the controller

```
class LikesController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @user = current_user.id
    @product = params[:product_id]
    likes = {user_id: @user, product_id: @product}
    @like = Like.new(likes)

    @like.save!
    if @like.save
      redirect_to user_path(@user)
    else
     redirect_to product_path
    end
  end


end
```

the buttton

```
<%= link_to "Like", product_likes_path(@product), method: :post %>
```

routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    root to: 'products#index'
    devise_for :users

    resources :users

    resources :users do
      resources :products do
        resources :likes
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try something along these lines:

Routes:

```
  Rails.application.routes.draw do
    root to: 'visitors#index'
    devise_for :users

    resources :users do 
      resources :products do 
        resources :likes
      end
    end

    resources :products do
      resource :likes
    end
  end
```

Which will give you something like:

```
  ... other routes ...

      user_product_likes GET    /users/:user_id/products/:product_id/likes(.:format)           likes#index
                         POST   /users/:user_id/products/:product_id/likes(.:format)           likes#create
   new_user_product_like GET    /users/:user_id/products/:product_id/likes/new(.:format)       likes#new
  edit_user_product_like GET    /users/:user_id/products/:product_id/likes/:id/edit(.:format)  likes#edit
       user_product_like GET    /users/:user_id/products/:product_id/likes/:id(.:format)       likes#show
                         PATCH  /users/:user_id/products/:product_id/likes/:id(.:format)       likes#update
                         PUT    /users/:user_id/products/:product_id/likes/:id(.:format)       likes#update
                         DELETE /users/:user_id/products/:product_id/likes/:id(.:format)       likes#destroy

  ... other routes ...
```

Then:

```
  <%= link_to "Like", user_product_likes_path(@user, @product), method: :post, remote: true %>
```

And in your LikesController:

```
  class LikesController < ApplicationController

    def new
      @like = Like.new(like_params)
    end

    def create
      @like = Like.new(like_params)
      if @like.save
        ... do something happy
      else
        ... do something sad
      end
    end

    private

    def like_params
      params.require(:likes).permit(:user_id, :product_id)
    end

  end
```

Untested, so buyer beware. You might need to fiddle with your like_params and other stuff.

Comment: Sure thing, glad to help. Please accept if you feel so inclined.